# Apache HTTP Server 2.4 LDAP (Active Directory) Authentication

Tags: active-directory, apache2

I have installed Apache 2.4 with PHP 5.4 on a Windows 2008 Server.  I am trying to authenticate against an Active Directory server.  I have uncommented the following in httpd.conf

```
LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
```

and I have created the following alias

```
Alias /Website "C:/Web/Aliases/Website"
<Location /Website>

# Using this to bind
AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=John Doe,OU=Accounts,OU=CA,OU=Country,OU=Company Name,DC=com"
AuthLDAPBindPassword "mypassword"
# search user
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://myserver/OU=Country,OU=Company,DC=com?poibri02?sub?(objectClass=*)"

AuthType Basic
AuthName "USE YOUR WINDOWS ACCOUNT"
AuthBasicProvider ldap
require valid-user

</Location>
```

However, when I try to access the website, I get a `500 Internal Server Error` and the error.log give the following

```
[Wed Jan 09 12:05:28.614839 2013] [ldap:error] [pid 3904:tid 1064] (70023)This function has not been implemented on this platform: AH01277: LDAP: Unable to add rebind cross reference entry. Out of memory?
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you find any solution/answer for this? I have same situation...

Comment: @mhesabi No, I didn't find a solution/answer for this...I ended up ditching Apache (for other reasons) and am using IIS instead.  I'm sure that there is a solution...keep looking! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solved this problem for me:

```
LDAPReferrals Off
```

Other tips gathered from [here](https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=4851&view=next) and [here](http://serverdown.ttwait.com/que/594366):

```
AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
# Use the password without quotes, e.g. password instead of "password"
AuthLDAPBindPassword password
```

However, these were not necessary for me.

Comment: LDAPReferrals Off solves the problem in my Apache 2.4 as well, but I need to know why this happens.